# How do I disable JavaScript in Microsoft Edge?

Tags: windows-10, javascript, microsoft-edge

The new Settings menu for Microsoft Edge does not seem to contain a way of disabling JavaScript. Going through Internet Options and disabling Active Scripting turns of JavaScript for IE11, but does not have an effect on Microsoft Edge.

Is there a way to disable JavaScript on the Microsoft Edge browser?

Comment: You may want to consider accepting the newer answer (from this month) since Microsoft has recently replaced their browser with a Chromium reskin, which means JavaScript can now be turned off, unlike what the (currently) accepted answer says.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Jan 2020 -- Edge 79 (Chromium Based)

If you have opted to [download](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/edge) the Chromium based Edge (at the time of writing this is the only way to get the Chromium Based version),you can disable javaScript

---

### Disable JavaScript for Browsing Purposes

You can get to the JavaScript Options by either visiting `edge://settings/content/javascript`, **OR** clicking on `Settings and more (Elipses) > Site Permissions > JavaScript`

From Here you can disable (block) JavaScript or enable (allow) it. You can also do this on a per site basis.

[image: JavaScript Settings]

---

### Disable JavaScript for Development Purposes

If you are using the DevTools (`Ctrl+Shift+I` **OR** Right-Click on page and Click `Inspect`), you can bring up the Command Menu and start typing `>disable JavaScript` and select the `Debugger Disable JavaScript` option. You can re-enable JavaScript by following the same steps, but instead start typing `>enable JavaScript`

**NOTE: you may or may not have to type the `>` (greater than symbol) depending on if it is already present.**

[image: Disable JavaScript using DevTools]

Answer (score 4):

#### How do I disable JavaScript in Microsoft Edge?

**Update**

Microsoft changed the Group Policies for Edge since I wrote this answer. Current Windows 10 builds don't allow you to turn off JavaScript in Edge via Group Policies.

---

You can change this using the Group Policy settings:

"Computer Configuration: > "Administrative Templates" > "Windows Components" > "Microsoft Edge"

The same settings can also be found under:

"User Configuration: > "Administrative Templates" > "Windows Components" > "Microsoft Edge"

---

#### Edge Group Policy Settings

> These Edge Group Policy Settings can be found under (User or
>   Computer)\Administrative Template\Windows Components\Microsoft Edge\
>   are:
>
> - Allows you to run scripts, like Javascript
> - Allows you to let people use autofill on websites
> - Allows you to let people send Do Not Track headers
> - Allows you to configured password manager
> - Allows you to run pop-ups
> - Stops address bar from showing search suggestions
> - Allows you to configure SmartScreen
> - Configure how Microsoft Edge treats cookies
> - Allows you to configured the Enterprise Site list
> - Sends all intranet traffic over to Internet Explorer

Source  [Edge Group Policy Settings](http://www.grouppolicy.biz/2015/07/edge-group-policy-settings/)

---

#### Further reading

- [Available policies for Microsoft Edge](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/mt270204.aspx)

Comment: For those of us not especially fluent in Windows, the `Computer Configuration` options can be edited through the **Edit group policy** tool. Just search on `Group` from the start menu. Took me a stupid amount of time to find that.

Comment: 1st, this post did not tell me what the path "*User Configuration/Administrative Template/Windows Components/Microsoft Edge*" meant. 2ndly, my windows 10 professional does not have this setting when I finally got to it. Did you copy this, or have you tried it out? I have 20 settings on Microsoft Edge on that path, but none about Javascript.

Comment: @BlessedGeek Microsoft changed the Group Policies for Edge since I wrote this answer. Current Windows 10 builds don't allow you to turn off JavaScript in Edge via Group Policies.

Comment: @DavidPostill So is there any other way to disable jscript in Edge now?

Comment: @Moab No idea. I don't run Windows 10 or Edge ...

Answer (score 4):

Latest build of Windows 10 Edge Microsoft has removed all these options to disable JavaScript.  It seems they really do want you to run JavaScript no matter what.  Often JavaScript is embedded into web pages to intercept mouse-clicks to prevent users from saving content like images.

Answer (score 2):

Computer Configuration / Administrative Templates / Windows Components / Microsoft Edge     Allows you to run scripts like Javascript

This setting lets you decide whether to let people run scripts, like JavaScript. This setting is enabled by default.

If you enable this setting, scripting is turned on for all your computers.

If you disable this setting, scripts can’t run.

Answer (score 0):

At least in my version of Windows 10 (10.0.14393), the Group Policy Setting *Allows you to run scripts, like Javascript* mentioned by DavidPostill and Botmaster is not available.. I think I remember the setting being there, but I can't find it anymore (I'm not 100% sure it was there "once upon a time", it might have been removed by an Update?).

If you want to enable or disable JavaScript, you now have to go to the **registry**, there's two possible locations for this setting:

> HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\MicrosoftEdge\Internet Settings\Zones\3

and

> HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy
>   Objects\{***xxxxx***}Machine\Software\Policies\Microsoft\MicrosoftEdge\Internet
>   Settings\Zones\3

(where ***xxxxx*** will be different for everyone).

I'm assuming Zone "3" is the "Internet" zone (as seen in InternetExplorer security settings).

There you will either find or need to create a REG_DWORD (32-bit) with the name **1400**

Values I know of:

- **0**: JavaScript enabled
- **2**: JavaScript disabled

**Note:** For me, the setting in HKLM had precedence over the setting in HKCU (e.g. changing the setting in HKCU had no effect for me).

Comment: This was my first answer to superuser.com and I got a downvote that I don't quite understand. Even the page [Available policies for Microsoft Edge](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/mt270204.aspx) of the accepted answer no longer has any information on how to disabled JavaScript in Microsoft Edge. So why was this downvoted?

Comment: Neither registry path in my Windows 10 pro has any setting you described.

Comment: Are you on a different version of Windows 10? Maybe this was added / removed in some version - I've just checked the registry again, mine contains both values (still on 10.0.14393)