# Javascript disable feature not works in microsoft edge

Tags: microsoft-edge

I tried to disable JS in ms edge using following steps:
"Computer Configuration: > "Administrative Templates" > "Windows Components" > "Microsoft Edge"

But even after disabling js, Code inside  tag is still running.

While in other browser like chrome, it does not runs.

Is this a bug in MS Edge?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I disable JavaScript in Microsoft Edge?](http://superuser.com/questions/955596/how-do-i-disable-javascript-in-microsoft-edge)

Comment: Dave, No. my concern here is, I have disabled JS in edge. But the code inside <script> tag still running. It should not actually. have you tried this?

Comment: Did you restart Edge after the change?

Comment: @fixer1234 , yes I tried but no luck. Have you ever faced this type of issue       in Win10 ms edge browser.