# how do i disable javascript in microsoft edge on win 10 home?

Tags: windows-10, javascript, microsoft-edge

I found a similar question ([How do I disable JavaScript in Microsoft Edge?](https://superuser.com/questions/955596/how-do-i-disable-javascript-in-microsoft-edge)), but the solution to it is not suitable to me described as Windows 10 Home does not contain the gpedit.msc

Comment: Please see my question and answer [Windows Starter Edition, Home and Home Premium do not include gpedit, how do I install it?](https://superuser.com/q/1018145)

Comment: So, just curious.... why do you want to disable JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

The answers to your linked question are incorrect and out-dated. Current Windows 10 builds don't allow you to turn off JavaScript in Edge via Group Policies.

So I assume it is also not possible in the home edition via a registry change.

Microsoft changed the Group Policies for Edge in the last year, they may change again in the future.

Maybe a browser extension can disable scripting in the future.